# How to place latest date in left order in the table

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

Current the talble has the latest date is placed in right order. 2020-08-13 / 2020-09-21...
but I'd like to make the latest date in left order ... 2020-09-21 / 2020-08-13...

I used DAX datediff and made the column putting numbers. but don't know how to sort it.

Comment: Use Sort axis maybe?

Comment: How are you getting this table in the first place? If you are pivoting, it might be as easy sorting by dating descending order before the pivot.